# Spring boot security - create root user on startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

My Spring Boot web app uses form authentication with spring-boot-security.
I have two tables:
**User**

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
    id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    //...
);
```

**Role**

```
CREATE TABLE role
(
    id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    r_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX sys_role_r_name_uindex ON sys_role (r_name);
```

**Join table**

```
CREATE TABLE ref_user_role
(
    user_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    role_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    // ...
);
```

In order to add more users with other roles/priviledges, one has to be of role `ROLE_ROOT` in **sys_role** table. This root user has to exist before the add-more-users action, logically.

**What I have tried** is that

- I ran a sql script containing the root-user-insertion statement before I deployed the app. Obviously, I had to also manually generate an encrypted password for this root user.
- I grammatically run an sql script to insert the root credentials. My concern is that it might not be safe to include my ROOT user credentials in the data.sql file. If I put encrypted version of the password, I have to encrypt it beforehand.

**Another way** I can think of is that I can create a root-creation-page ONLY the first time the app starts. I will need a secret code(only the I and the app knows) in addition to the username and password so that no other random people can create the root account.

Are these the common ways to do this?
If not, what are some of the good ways?

Comment: You can execute a delete/insert or update/insert query pragmatically with a generated encrypted password at startup

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Spring Boot, all you have to do is to place schema.sql and data.sql scripts within resources classpath.

The schema.sql will be in charge of creating your tables and associations between them, and the data.sql will be in charge of initializing your tables with data, so you can put there your insert into tables statements.

when you upload the service these scripts will be executed automatically by Spring Boot each upload.

for further reading take a look at:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-database-initialization

Comment: Thanks. I sort of already did what you suggested in my first method. My concern is that it might not be safe to include my ROOT user credentials in the data.sql file. If I put encrypted version of the password, I have to encrypt it beforehand. I want to know if there is a more elegant way to do so.

Comment: why do you believe that it's not safe? this script is not accessible via you service.

Comment: I always believe that put passcode in a file is a bad idea. I understand that if my server, source code repo, and my workstation are completely safe from hacking, then storing password in a file has no harm.

Comment: What about encoding and salting your passwords?